# Is it possible to update the download location for a file in Chrome in Karate UI to the target folder?

Tags: download, automated-tests, karate

I am using Karate UI for a test as part of which some steps involve the downloading of a file and validating the existence of the same.

Is it possible to update the download location of the file to target folder instead of default downloads folder?
How can I configure driver in karate config to get the file downloaded at the preferred location?

I have tried using userDataDir, but this isn't working.

Any help will be appreciated.